# Convert a string to an array of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, arrays, string

How can I convert a string to an array of objects?

I am working with the following string

```
var s = "[{role:staff, storeId: 1234}, {role:admin, storeId: 4321}]";
```

and i want to be able to convert it to a .net object such as

```
public class StaffAccountObj
{
    public string role { get; set; }
    public string storeId { get; set; }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? This looks like JSON but implemented badly. Can you affect this string?

Comment: It's not valid JSON (unquoted strings) but maybe you could use the AlmostJson.NET library. /s I suggest fixing the input so you can simply use a JSON deserializer like [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

Comment: @DavidG do you remember when you had only 6 points? And you'd never heard of JSON? At least point them in the right direction. All you are doing is raising the bar for an entry level question.

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 Not at all, I'm asking if the user has tried anything yet, that's not an entry bar, it's giving us a head start and ensuring the OP learns from this experience rather than someone giving them a code dump.

Comment: there are two ways to address this, if you have access to the data that's generating the "JSON", you can adjust it and make the data valid and use a JSON parser.  If not, you can do some crafty string splitting to parse out the data.

Comment: OP may not even have direct control of the data being parsed.  Sometimes stuff doesn't follow specs entirely and you have to deal with whatever data a 3rd party opts to send to you.

Comment: My question isn't about JSON, its about convert a string to an object. I have tried to use the Split method but I was just wondering if there would be a cleaner approach using JObject or JsonConvert

Comment: @user2366842 yes but I would push like hell to get it fixed. Writing a custom JSON parser is a non-trivial task, and likely a never-ending stream of edge cases due to invalid input.

Comment: @test The point is that it's not valid JSON so you can't use `JObject` or `JsonConvert`, unless you fix the source data - is that possible?

Comment: I guess it depends on what data is being passed through.  If you know you'll never run into edge cases, and your data will continue to be as simple as given in the example, it shouldn't be much of a problem.  If not....entirely different ballgame.  I certainly do agree that getting the source data corrected is the best approach though.

Comment: @test Think about this, what happens if the role value was `admin,staff`? In your input, that would be a nightmare to parse.

Comment: Nope i can't change it, the source will always be a string like in the example

Comment: If you have no control over the source data, then parsing it out using string splitting and the like will probably be your solution.  This may not be as big of an issue, if there's some guaruntees behind the data that it won't contain (for example) a comma or a square bracket.

Comment: @user2366842 thank you

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use a regular expression to find the matches. Now this is a bit fragile, but if you are sure your input is in this format then this will work:

```
var s = "[{role:staff, storeId: 1234}, {role:admin, storeId: 4321}]";

//There is likely a far better RegEx than this...
var staffAccounts = Regex
    .Matches(s, @"\{role\:(\w*), storeId\: (\d*)}")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => new StaffAccountObj
    {
        role = m.Groups[1].Value,
        storeId = m.Groups[2].Value
    });
```

And loop through them like this:

```
foreach (var staffAccount in staffAccounts)
{
    var role = staffAccount.role;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/), since your string is a JSON compaible one:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<StaffAccountObj>>(s);
```